# Android: HttpPost is sent as GET and not as POST: how to correct that?

Tags: android

It looks like my Android `httpPost` is limited to 5Kbytes!

```
public static boolean upload(String url, String content)
        throws IOException {

    Log.d(TAG, "upload data begin to url:" + url);

    HttpClient httpClient = createHttpClient();
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);

    Uri.Builder builder = uri.buildUpon();
    builder.appendQueryParameter("key", content);
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(builder.build().toString());

    try {
        HttpResponse postResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        int statusCode = postResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        postResponse.getEntity().consumeContent();
        return statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK;
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "upload data failure", e);
        throw e;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "upload data failure", e);
        throw e;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "upload data failure", e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

When looking at the Apache logs I got:

```
[error] [client ] request failed: URI too long (longer than 8190)
```

It looks like it is sent as `GET` and not `POST`!

Comment: there is no body in your post

Comment: I just checked my apache log and I got: [error] [client ] request failed: URI too long (longer than 8190). So it looks like it is sent as GET and not as POST: any idea ?

Comment: Some proxies in between change post to get.

Comment: @yarek, yes, that's because, like I said, you don't have a body. you are putting your content in the query instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `POST` to begin with, not `GET`.

On another note, theoretically there is no limit, it is only limited by the value configured. See the Apache docs here for more information:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestline

Answer (score 0):

> So it looks like it is sent as GET and not as POST

No. You just put everything in the URL. The constructor takes the URL, not the `POST` body.

Since HttpClient was removed from the Android SDK in Android 6.0, I cannot readily link you to Android's `HttpPost` documentation. However, AFAIK, it is similar to [the 4.5.1 API](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html), where the constructor parameter is the URL.